# Why can't I send messages to my friends?

Tags: dota-2

I have friends, they're online but I just cannot message them.

When I click on someone and select "Send message...", nothing happens. I checked the options already but I cannot seem to find any solution. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: May I ask why you unticked my answer ? Was there something wrong that I would need to edit ? Don't hesitate to tell me ^_^

Comment: I accepted it a while back as an answer but realised quickly this was not really a solution for me but a annoying work around.  I do not like steam popups when inside a game, often with or without a game I need to click in the popup area and cant because of all the popups.  But I do want to know if a friend is logging into the game I play.

Comment: I see, unfortunately, unless the editor of any game on steam decide to implement a chat system you have to use the one from the steam overlay. In dota 2 however if you want to have a private chat room with your friend, an easy way to do it is either to create a chat room or to all join the same [guild](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=154054221)

Answer (score 4):

Shift tab, the chat windows opened in the steam overlay

Comment: Seriously? How annoying is that? I cannot even see if someone is messaging me this way... epicly flawed

Comment: @MennoGouw It depends on your steam settings, you can have a sound and an in game notification but you fcan set it up in the Steam properties

Comment: @MennoGouw but dont be mistaken, it **always** open in the steam layout, the only thing you can change is the notifications

Answer (score 1):

Honestly the best way I find that you can overcome this problem is by changing your game application setting to windowed mode (make sure that the settings are full screen windowed). Then you can alt+tab and flick between chats (Either have that chats opened before starting dota 2 or right click on steam on the task bar click friends and so on and so forth).

If that doesn't work then it may be a problem with your steam application.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that has worked for me 100% of the time.

First, go to Steam.

Second, click library.

Third, right click Dota 2 ->properties.

Finally, ***untick*** and ***tick back*** the box next to ENABLE STEAM COMMUNITY IN GAME.